# Entity Framework validation error for missing field, but it's not missing?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have an expense entity which has a required relationship with an expense period. It's defined like:

```
public class UserExpense
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int ExpenseId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime DateIncurred { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual DateTime LastModified { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual ExpenseType ExpenseType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual decimal TotalAmount { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public virtual UserExpensePeriod ExpensePeriod { get; set; }

    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<ExpenseReceipt> Receipts { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectStatus Status { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm adding a new expense, I have a method which looks up an existing period to which the expense applies, or creates a new period and returns it. This is the code:

```
public UserExpensePeriod CreateOrGetExpensePeriod(int userId, DateTime date)
{
    var existing = _context.UserExpensePeriods.FirstOrDefault(e => e.User.UserId == userId && e.StartDate <= date && e.EndDate >= date);
    if (existing != null)
    {
        return existing;
    }

    var user = _context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserId == userId);
    var newPeriod = new UserExpensePeriod()
    {
        StartDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, 1),
        EndDate = new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(date.Year, date.Month)),
        Status = ExpenseStatus.Draft,
        Name = date.ToString("MMMM") + " " + date.Year.ToString(),
        User = user
    };

    _context.UserExpensePeriods.Add(newPeriod);
    return newPeriod;
}
```

Here's the method which creates the new expense. The mapping service is an abstraction of Automapper. MileageExpense is based on Expense:

```
public void CreateMileageExpense(MileageExpenseViewModel model, int createdByUserId, string ipAddress, string userAgent)
{
    var user = _unitOfWork.UserRepository.GetById(createdByUserId);

    var expense = _mappingService.Map<MileageExpenseViewModel, MileageExpense>(model);
    expense.DateAdded = DateTime.UtcNow;
    expense.LastModified = expense.DateAdded;
    expense.ExpensePeriod = _unitOfWork.ExpenseRepository.CreateOrGetExpensePeriod(createdByUserId, expense.DateAdded);
    expense.DistanceMeasurement = user.Company.Jurisdiction.DistanceMeasurement;
    expense.EngineSize = _unitOfWork.CompanyRepository.GetEngineSize(model.EngineSizeId);
    expense.MileageRatesApplied = CalculateMileageAmountByEngineSize(expense);

    if (model.SelectedProjectId.HasValue)
    {
        expense.Project = _unitOfWork.ProjectRepository.GetById(model.SelectedProjectId.Value);
    }

    _unitOfWork.ExpenseRepository.AddMileageExpense(expense);
    _unitOfWork.SaveChanges();           

}
```

When I debug I can see that this method returns the correct period (in this case it's not created as one already exists).

I then add the new expense to the data context DbSet. When I save changes I get an error telling me that the ExpensePeriod is a required field.

Does anyone know why this might be happening? The Pk is populated and as I'm using dependency injection the retrieval and add are done within the same context.

Many thanks for your help,
John

Comment: show the code that calls `CreateOrGetExpensePeriod(...)` and creates/saves the new `Expense`

Comment: How about `return _context.UserExpensePeriods.Add(newPeriod)`? Also, depending on when you commit, it may make sense to check against `_context.UserExpensePeriods.Local` as well as `_context.UserExpensePeriods`.

Comment: Thanks but the UserPeriod already exists in the DB, so is returned in the first section of the function.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried saving and commiting the UserExpensePeriods object before adding UserExpense?

```
_context.SaveChanges(true);
_context.AcceptAllChanges();
```

Comment: Hi Felipe, when I debug no new period is added as one already exists, so there is nothing to commit.