# Error inserting record with entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am sorry if it has already been answered but I can't find any solution. Here is my (little) problem. Also all my apologies if the terms I use are approximate, I am far from being a skilled C# developer

Note that I think my problem is similar to this one [Entity Framework validation error for missing field, but it's not missing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21589261/entity-framework-validation-error-for-missing-field-but-its-not-missing)

I have a table "Tweets" with a tweet_id field (bigint) which is my primary key.

I use the following class to load the table :

```
class TwitterDbContext : DbContext
{
    public TwitterDbContext() : base("Twitter")
    {

    }
    public DbSet<Stream> Streams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<StreamParameter> StreamParameters { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tweet> Tweets { get; set; }
}

public class Tweet
{
    public Tweet()
    {

    }
    [Key]
    public long tweet_id { get; set; }
    public string tweet { get; set; }
    public long creator { get; set; }
    public double latitude { get; set; }
    public double longitude { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public DateTime created_at { get; set; }
    public DateTime registered_at { get; set; }
    public long? in_reply_to { get; set; }
    public bool retweeted { get; set; }
}
```

I have an other class to store within the code execution all the fields used by the Tweet table. For the need here, let's imagine I manually create it that way

```
        private void Test_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        Twts twtReceived = new Twts();
        twtReceived.tweet_id = 1;
        twtReceived.tweet = "test";
        twtReceived.creator = 1;
        twtReceived.latitude = -1;
        twtReceived.longitude = -1;
        twtReceived.language = "a";
        twtReceived.created_at = DateTime.Now;
        twtReceived.registered_at = DateTime.Now;
        twtReceived.in_reply_to = 1;
        twtReceived.retweeted = true;

        AddTweet(twtReceived);


    }
```

Now here is the AddTweet method

```
static public void AddTweet(Twts twtReceived)
    {
        try
        {
            // update the tweet data in the database
            using (var TwitterDb = new TwitterDbContext())
            {

                Tweet twt = new Tweet() 
                {
                    tweet_id = twtReceived.tweet_id,
                    tweet = twtReceived.tweet,
                    creator = twtReceived.creator,
                    longitude = twtReceived.longitude,
                    latitude = twtReceived.latitude,
                    language = twtReceived.language,
                    created_at = twtReceived.created_at,
                    registered_at = twtReceived.registered_at,
                    in_reply_to = twtReceived.in_reply_to,
                    retweeted = twtReceived.retweeted   
                };
                TwitterDb.Tweets.Add(twt);
                TwitterDb.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.InnerException.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I constantly have the same error message:

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'tweet_id', table
>   'Twitter.dbo.Tweets'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

The thing is that when I spy on "TwitterDb.Tweets.Local" after     TwitterDb.Tweets.Add(twt); I correctly have tweet_id set to 1.

Any idea where is the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try marking your tweet_id field with following (instead of just [Key]), if this is a primary key column where you want to provide values yourself

```
[Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

If it is an auto-increment, then remove explicit assignments to this field and mark it as 'Identity' instead:

```
[Required, Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

Comment: Maksim Satsikau, thanks for the reply. Not an autoincrement. It is "default" bigint set as primary key

Comment: actually, got it wrong the first time around - DatabaseGenerated.Identity would mark the field as an autoincrement. In your case DatabaseGeneratedOption.None does exactly what you need - updated the answer